# How to change color of a 3D scatter plot w.r.t. one value other than X,Y,Z

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray, scatter-plot

I have 4 numpy arrays for X, Y, Z, and Values.

```
X= [20,30,50,60,..]
Y= [25,35,55,65,...]
Z= [5,6,7,8,...]
Values = [-8,5,0.8,-1.2....]
```

All arrays are of the same size and the index of all arrays is matched. Eg. X[1],Y[1],Z[1],Values[1] all corresponds to same point.

Based on X, Y, and Z I have to make a scatter plot. But colour of the scatter plot should change according to the Values array. If abs value of items from the Values array is high then scatter point should have colour red and gradually change to blue if value is less. Any colormap will do.

I have managed to plot a 3d scatter plot using X,Y,Z but I am not sure how to associate Values with it.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z)
```

Comment: `ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, c=Values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Colormap Normalization](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#twoslopenorm-different-mapping-on-either-side-of-a-center)

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 50
X = np.random.rand(N)
Y = np.random.rand(N)
Z = np.random.rand(N)

values = np.random.randn(N)

vmin, vcenter, vmax = -2, 1, 2
divnorm = colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=vmin, vcenter=vcenter, vmax=vmax)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")

p = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=values, cmap="coolwarm", norm=divnorm)

cb = fig.colorbar(p, extend="both")
cb.set_ticks(np.arange(vmin, vmax + 1))

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image: 3D scatter plot]